Excel transforming dates ddmmyy to yymmdd
Having a date issue.  When I enter date in excel as folles today being 20-04-24 ,  excel transforme it into 2020-04-24 .  So it's mistaking the day for the year.

What is your cell format? And what is your date format in Windows?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The current format is date "*March 14,2012"  the second down the list for the "English canada" location.  When it comes to the pc the short date format is YYYY-MM-DD .  Long date is April 20, 2024

On Excel 365, I duplicated your settings, but I get the correct date : "April 20, 2024".

Even if I don't copy paste if I simply enter the following "20-04-24" it instantly converts the year to 2020 and the date to 24

What if you use / instead of - for data entry?

@KenJohnson: This is what I did, and entering both "20-04-24" or "20-04-2024" gave "April 20, 2024". Are you using Office 365? (Add to your comment @harrymc for me to be notified.)

@harrymc yep even if I use the dishes same thing.  My current version of excel is the version 2302 .  I believe it is part of the office 365

@KenJohnson: My Excel version is "2403 Build 16.0.17425.20176) 64-bit". Not sure that this will explain these different results, but try to update. Is Windows Settings > Windows Update > Advanced options has checked "Receive updates for other Microsoft products"?

In your Windows format the order is YMD and this order is retained. Press Ctrl+; to see your system date format.

@MGonet when I do that gives me 2024-04-20.  My system won't let me make any of these changes locked by my local IT I'll reach out to them .  Thank you for your assistance

@KenJohnson , I suggest you write an answer to this when you have figured out your fix. just tick, "[v] Write an answer to my own question"

@Hannu as soon as I do yep.  Now I have found some weird success by changing the keyboard from English canada to English US which then pastes the data correctly but excel doesn't recognize that it's a date
